# SQL - Setting a maximum number when incrementing a value by 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I want increment `difficulty` by 1 but the value of `difficulty` should not go past 3. How do I do that?

This is my query

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ticket
                          SET status = 'open',
                          difficulty = difficulty + 1
                          WHERE ticketid = '$_POST[ticketid]'")
```

Comment: Add a WHERE difficulty < 3 clause, and watch out for SQL injection here.

Comment: you can add trigger for update and insert where difficuly <= 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Schema

```
create table ticket
(   ticketid int auto_increment primary key,
    status varchar(20) not null,
    difficulty int not null
);
insert ticket(status,difficulty) values (0,0),(0,0);    -- 2 rows
```

run this query a bunch of times:

```
update ticket
set status ='open',
difficulty=least(difficulty+1,3)
where ticketid=2;
```

Now look at data

```
select * from ticket;
+----------+--------+------------+
| ticketid | status | difficulty |
+----------+--------+------------+
|        1 | 0      |          0 |
|        2 | open   |          3 |
+----------+--------+------------+
```

See [Mysql Comparison functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ticket_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ticketid']);    
$query=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ticket
                              SET status = 'open',
                              difficulty = least(difficulty + 1,3)
                              WHERE ticketid = '$ticket_id'")
```

Note that I added `ticket_id` escaping to fix the SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a if statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket` (
    `ticketid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `difficulty` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ticketid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO ticket (difficulty, status) VALUES (0,0);

UPDATE 
   ticket 
SET 
   `difficulty` = IF(`difficulty` < 3,`difficulty` + 1, 3) 
WHERE 
    `ticketid`=1;
```

For more information have a look at https://www.ask-sheldon.com/conditions/.